# Navigation menu centered by the image

Tags: html, css, image, menu, centering

I have a problem with centering my nav menu. I want to my logo be perfectly centered on website and links to be around it inline. When I center my whole menu, indeed it's centered, but my image isn't in the center of a website.

Is there a solution to center my navigation menu by the logo?

```
<header>
 <div class="nav-desktop">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><img src="https://images82.fotosik.pl/410/7d70ec9229c54fe2.png"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Awards</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>              
            </ul>           
        </nav>
    </div>
  </header>



   header
{
  background: #3f3f3f;
}
.nav-desktop
{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.nav-desktop ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;   
}

.nav-desktop ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav-desktop ul li img
{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And here's my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/brq8f7nz/1/

Thanks for help!

Comment: Make menu items fixed width and then add to css `margin:auto` to block `.nav-desktop ul`. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I know of achieving this is to set the same `width` attribute to all your `<li>` elements, except the one holding the image:

```
   <li class="menuli"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li class="menuli"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
   <li><img src="....."></li>
   <li class="menuli"><a href="#">Awards</a></li>
   <li class="menuli"><a href="#">Team</a></li>
```

in the CSS:

```
.menuli
{
   width:300px;
   text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: @KacperT Glad I could help. Happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

**only add**  `nav` style  and remove `padding-top: 30px;` in **.nav-desktop** class

```
nav{
  text-align:center;
}
```

**[Revise Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brq8f7nz/4/)**

```css
header {
  background: #3f3f3f;
}

nav {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-desktop {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-desktop ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-desktop ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-desktop ul li img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="nav-desktop">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><img src="https://images82.fotosik.pl/410/7d70ec9229c54fe2.png"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Awards</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Unfortunetaly it doesn't work. Nav is centered, but my logo isn't in the center.

Comment: logo is horizontally center ... if you require logo center vertically ?

Comment: i updated my answer please check it . nav & logo also center horizontally & vertically

Answer (score 0):

I got it... my ul just got left padding and it was a reason why my logo wasn't in the center but more to the right.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Yes I always forget that too :D Best practice to avoid this is set always at beggining padding and margin to zero to all items you are customizing. Then you can set any padding and margin and it will then mostly behave as you expect.